# The system logs in immediately after logging out. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, logout

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with multiple desktop environments on it (LXDE, KDE, XFCE, Unity). When I try to log out it logs in again without asking password. It happens on various environments.
Also, I see black screen when I wake the PC up after suspending, but Ctrl+Alt+F1 opens the terminal. However, shutdown works

Comment: My guess is you have auto-login enabled.  Turn the feature off to allow switching between environments more easily.

Comment: I checked out in Ubuntu's system settings, it was disabled.

Comment: Hmm... it sounds like you had the same problem as me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062050/ubuntu-logs-me-back-in-immediately-after-logout

Comment: I have the same problem, starting a few days ago after an update. Also, switch user doesn't work and gives me my own account for a new login. Maybe the problem will go away after the upgrade to 18.04 (not yet offered by the software updater, but hopefully coming soon).

Comment: @RainerSchulze-Pillot: let me know if that works. I was reluctant to upgrade in case it made the problem worse.

Comment: Miraculously, the problem disappeared today (without an upgrade to 18.04).

Comment: @RainerSchulze-Pillot Did you install/upgrade any specific packages recently?

Comment: I don't really now. I ran an update or two recommended by the software updater without looking at its content. Meanwhile I upgraded to 18.04 (actually, it became a new install because I accidentally pulled the plug during the upgrade), 18.04 is so far running fine.

Comment: @RainerSchulze-Pillot: Alright, I guess I'll have to try an upgrade to 18.04 and hope for the best.