# Ubuntu logs me back in immediately after logout

Tags: 16.04, login, session, logout, groups

A few days ago I noticed that when I log *out* of Ubuntu 16, the screens go black and then I am immediately logged back *in* again. I do *not* have autologin enabled.

Observations of other strange behaviour that seemed to start at around the same time:

- I can no longer access `docker` with using `sudo`, although if I run `newgrp docker`, a new shell starts and I can run `docker` with `sudo`. And yes, my user *is* in the docker group.
- I sometimes get a "The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer" message on login. I'd never seen this message before, and it doesn't *always* appear, still trying to figure out exactly which conditions trigger it.

This is not a new installation or set up. It's been stable for at least a year. I know that in the last few weeks, there were some updates that got recently applied, and I think all this might have started after the last reboot, but I'm not sure what's causing these problems. Has anyone else noticed this sort of behaviour, or have any debugging suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I upgraded to 18.04 and the problem seems to have gone away. I wish I could explain the problem and solution better, but that's all I've got.